# How to extract matches in multiple rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am still learning R and I have a basic question. I have a data frame (`df`) that looks like this:

```
    Factor   P1    P2    P3    P4    P5
 1      A  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 2      A FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 3      B  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 4      B  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 5      C FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 6      C  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

df = data.frame("Factor" = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
            "P1" = c("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE"),
            "P2" =c("FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE"),
            "P3" = c("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE"), 
            "P4" = c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"), 
            "P5" = c("TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE"))
```

I would like to collapse the common `Factor` across the `df` so that whenever `TRUE` is present in either rows for the same `Factor`, it will be reported as `TRUE`. Something like this:

```
Factor    P1     P2     P3     P4     P5
  A     TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
  B     TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
  C     TRUE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```

Could someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two steps here:

1. Convert all the `P` columns to logical vectors with `as.logical`
2. Group on `Factor`, and then use `any` to see if any of the values for each `P` for each `Factor` are `TRUE`

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame("Factor" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), "P1" = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE"), "P2" = c("FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"), "P3" = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE"), "P4" = c("FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"), "P5" = c("TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE"))
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Factor), as.logical) %>%
  group_by(Factor) %>%
  summarise_all(any)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   Factor P1    P2    P3    P4    P5   
#>   <fct>  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1 A      TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#> 2 B      TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
#> 3 C      TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A different `tidyverse` option could be:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, val, -Factor) %>%
 group_by(Factor, var) %>%
 mutate(val = ifelse(any(val), TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
 distinct() %>%
 spread(var, val)

  Factor P1    P2    P3    P4    P5   
  <fct>  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 A      TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
2 B      TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
3 C      TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE
```

First, it transforms the data from wide to long, excluding the "Factor" variable. Second, it groups by "Factor" and the other variables. Third, it checks the condition. Finally, it removes the duplicate rows and returns it back to wide format.

Or based on the idea of @Calum You:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(-Factor), as.logical) %>%
 group_by(Factor) %>%
 summarise_all(funs(sum(.) > 0))
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(-Factor), as.logical) %>%
 group_by(Factor) %>%
 summarise_all(funs(!all(!.)))
```

With base R:

```
x <- cbind(df[, 1], data.frame(apply(df[, -1], 2, function(x) as.logical(x))))
colnames(x) <- colnames(df)

aggregate(. ~ Factor, x, function(x) any(x))

  Factor   P1   P2    P3    P4    P5
1      A TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2      B TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
3      C TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or:

```
aggregate(. ~ Factor, x, function(x) sum(x) > 0)
```

Or:

```
aggregate(. ~ Factor, x, function(x) !all(!x))
```